# How can I send YAML over AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yaml

> Please focus on the *technical* aspect of this question, and not on the *why*. The why is obvious: YAML is the most human-readable data serialization format available to man. And therefore, the best.

How can I send YAML via an XMLHttpRequest from the client to the server, without first converting it to JSON, XML or another format?

I am using JavaScript for the client-side code, I can use jQuery if needed. My server-side language of choice is PHP.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_send_method), the `send()` method of XMLHttpRequest:

> Accepts a single parameter containing the content to be sent with the request. The W3C draft states that **this parameter may be any type available to the scripting language as long as it can be turned into a text string**, with the exception of the DOM document object. *[Emphasis my own]*

YAML is a text string. Can it be sent and subsequently parsed correctly on the server-side *without* using another data serialization format like json, xml etc?

Comment: You realize that AJAX requests are a plain regular HTTP request like any other? They just happen to be done in the background of a webpage by code, instead via direct human intervention. If some data format can be sent via HTTP by clicking/submitting a form, then it can go via AJAX, because they're essentially exactly the same process.

Comment: **cv-pls**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062649/how-can-i-send-yaml-over-ajax/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()) an [appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332129/yaml-mime-type) content type and [send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()) it.

```
// xhr is an instance of XMLHttpRequest which has been open()ed and had event handlers set on it already
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/x-yaml");
xhr.send(string_of_yaml_formatted_data);
```

Note, that most server side languages won't parse it automatically, so you'll need to read the raw data from the POST request body and parse it yourself.

e.g. in PHP:

```
$raw_yaml = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = yaml_parse($raw_yaml);
```

*Note: `yaml_parse()` requires [PECL yaml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php) >= 0.4.0*