# Spring Boot - RestController Deserializing YAML Uploads?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, yaml

How can I configure a Spring Boot RestController to accept YAML uploads?

The following results in a 415. I can see from debugging that the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances in my Spring context only support `[application/json;charset=UTF-8, application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]`. I can't be the only Spring Boot user trying to do this, and I'm surprised it doesn't *just work* - most things do in Spring Boot!

I've got the YAML dataformat in my POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My RestController has a method thus:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/", consumes="application/yaml")
public String upload(@RequestBody Declaration declaration) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

And my test:

```
@Test
public void triggersConvergence() throws Exception {
    ClassPathResource fixture = new ClassPathResource("declaration.yml");
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/yaml");
    requestHeaders.add("Accept", "application/json");

    URI uri = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:"+port);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)fixture.contentLength()];
    fixture.getInputStream().read(bytes);
    RequestEntity<byte[]> postRequest = new RequestEntity<byte[]>(bytes, requestHeaders, HttpMethod.POST, uri);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.exchange(postRequest, String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
    assertThat(response.getBody(), is("Converged org my-lovely-org"));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to upload or do you want to submit an object represented as YAML. As both are totally different questions (and solutions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this functionality is not available in Spring it's easy to add using [`YAMLMapper`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.6.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLMapper.html) it in 2 simple steps:

1. Define your own [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) that supports [`Content-Type: application/x-yaml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332129/yaml-mime-type):

   ```
   final class YamlJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
       YamlJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
           super(new YAMLMapper(), MediaType.parseMediaType("application/x-yaml"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register your converter:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class YamlConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
           converters.add(new YamlJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
       }
   }
   ```

Enjoy controller methods *consuming* and *producing* [`application/x-yaml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332129/yaml-mime-type) from POJOs.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly the sort of light-touch solution I was hoping for you.

Comment: No idea why the word "you" appears there!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

### Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

### Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-yaml")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> receiveYaml(@RequestBody final String yaml) {
    //unserialize yaml
}
```

### Request example using curl:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-yaml" --header "Accept: */*" -d "invoice: 34843
date   : 2001-01-23
bill-to: &id001
    given  : Chris
    family : Dumars
    address:
        lines: |
            458 Walkman Dr.
            Suite #292
        city    : Royal Oak
        state   : MI
        postal  : 48046
ship-to: *id001
product:
    - sku         : BL394D
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
    - sku         : BL4438H
      quantity    : 1
      description : Super Hoop
      price       : 2392.00
tax  : 251.42
total: 4443.52
comments: >
    Late afternoon is best.
    Backup contact is Nancy
    Billsmer @ 338-4338."
```

Comment: The `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml` is not needed to be able to consume `application/x-yaml` in `receiveYaml(@RequestBody final String yaml)`.

Comment: You are right. But is required if you want to deserialize the yaml using `new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());`

Comment: You can declare the param using POJO's type instead of `String`, thus could avoid deserialize explicitly using `ObjectMapper`. BTW, it could support yaml & json at the same time, thus no need to add `consumes = "application/x-yaml"`, unless you only want to accept yaml.