# Is it possible to add complex extension in ng-file-upload plugin to accept specific files?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using **ng-file-upload** plugin to upload files and I'd like to select files with specific extension. In my case it's **.info.system.yaml** extension. I've looked through examples and see only short variants like **.pdf**, **.docs** and etc.

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) I've tried **ngf-pattern="'.info.system.yaml'"** and **ngf-accept=".info.system.yaml"** but it doesn't work.

```html
<button class="btn btn-default"
     ngf-select="selectFiles($files, $invalidFiles)"
     ngf-pattern="'.info.system.yaml'"
     ngf-accept=".info.system.yaml"
     multiple>Select File</button>
```

Comment: Can you please check this out:

<input placeholder="upload" type="file" name="info_system_yaml" ngf-select="selectFiles($files, $invalidFiles)" ng-model="newpackage.info.system.yaml" accept=".info.system.yaml" ngf-accept="'.info.system.yaml'" ngf-max-size="15MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile"
/>

Comment: @AbuSufian Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: what is your file extension '.info.system.yaml' or just '.yaml' ?

Comment: @AbuSufian I'd like to accept the files with endings '.info.system.yaml'. For example, 'test1.info.system.yaml' or 'myData.info.system.yaml'. I took a look at validation code in plugin [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/src/validate.js) in function globStringToRegex and it should work, but I don't understand why it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

The ng-file-upload module uses the FileApi which will accept all MIME types or also known as a Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions or MIME type https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml. Unfortunately, yaml is not on the list at all/has not been accepted yet reference stackoverflow answer here
[YAML mime type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332129/yaml-mime-type).