# How to send YML as request body in POSTMAN

Tags: post, postman, http-post, rasa

I have an YML file :

```
{language: en, pipeline: null, policies: null}

version: '2.0'
intents: [greet, goodbye, affirm, deny, mood_great, mood_unhappy, bot_challenge]
responses:
  utter_greet:
  - {text: 'Hey! How are you?'}
  utter_cheer_up:
  - {text: 'Here is something to cheer you up:', image: 'https://i.imgur.com/nGF1K8f.jpg'}
  utter_did_that_help:
  - {text: 'Did that help you?'}
  utter_happy:
  - {text: 'Great, carry on!'}
  utter_goodbye:
  - {text: Bye}
  utter_iamabot:
  - {text: 'I am a bot, powered by Rasa.'}
session_config: {session_expiration_time: 60, carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true}
```

Now How to send a POST request using POSTMAN...
I need to send a POST request but in POSTMAN I'm unable to set the requestbody type to x-yaml.?

Comment: Postman allows you to send raw text as body.. just pick the option Raw and pick text. That should work. and if you go to the headers, display the hidden ones. and change the content type or any other field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/43deac65a6de60ac46b3

An example collection just click import> using link in postman and paste it

so what you have to do in is set body as text and content type as application/x-yaml

[image]

[image]

[YAML media type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332129/yaml-media-type)

Comment: Just as a note: You have to add a SECOND Content-Type header because you cannot modify the existing one. Too me quite a while to figure this out.